# Specific narrow-topic question considered as duplicate of a general question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760661/what-happens-if-many-connections-to-a-flask-server-arrive-at-the-same-time), that, even if it's not the most interesting question in the world, could be useful (many people often question such usage of Flask, for instance). I made the question rather specific and narrow, with minimal reproducible code, etc. and by examining the different situations that could arise.

This question was considered as duplicate of "very general questions":

- [Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production) => that was not exactly my question, and also the answers are rather general "No it's not safe, ...".
- [Handling multiple requests in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672753/handling-multiple-requests-in-flask)
- "Flask by default serves only one request at a time" => it doesn't show what happens if we ask many requests at same time, etc., and also doesn't really cover the answer since *"though it can be configured to handle concurrent requests (with app.run(threaded=True))"*

To me, a specific-question was closed as duplicate of a "general purpose" question that doesn't really answer it.

**In such situations, how could I suggest the goal of this question was more specific?**

I might be wrong - since my question is highly downvoted, and comments in the question show a consensus proving that my question in non-interesting for SO, but really I think here the goal of the question was more specific than the linked-questions. 
To improve myself for future questions, what was really wrong?

Comment: In what way does the dupe not satisfy the question again?  "No it's not safe to use in production" implies that you're hitting it with more than one connection, and "serves only one request at a time" implies that you're not likely going to be deploying this in production.  The result that I get from reading those two dupes if, "If you deploy the vanilla Flask app into production by *itself*, bad things are prone to happen."

Comment: At that point I feel like the main thrust of your question is moot; it doesn't matter how many users try to connect to your development server since it's not a state that would ever reflect production behavior or traffic.

Comment: How does the duplicate fail to answer your question?

Comment: @Servy For instance the "Use WSGI" answers don't explain **how it would directly solve** the "multiple requests at same time" problem. Let's say the nginx server passes the multiple requests to Flask via WSGI, the fact we're using WSGI doesn't explain how the multiple requests at same time will be handled by Flask.

Comment: So are you asking a question more specifically about how WSGI operates with Python/Flask @Basj?

Comment: @Makoto No, I was not asking about WSGI. I asked a specific problem, people said "It's a duplicate of this question. Its answer is Use WSGI", etc. but I wanted to question the core usage, without WSGI at first.

Comment: @Basj Flask is _not_ a server. That's the point I made in my comments already, amongst others. "Handled by Flask" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @roganjosh Wrong. It embeds a lightweight minimal server. I'm using it like this currently, and it works, even with many thousands of connections per day. *Even if I trust you that it's a bad idea to do it*, the goal of my question was to understand why internally it would be bad to use it actually, what would break, etc. When someone say "Don't use X, but use X with Y + Z", it's natural to want to understand which reasons would make X alone to fail, etc. 
 -- 
Let's close this going-nowhere discussion.

Comment: I'm not _wrong_. It is _not a server_. The framework works with multiple other servers... it's still Flask. To consider the development server as part of Flask is nonsense. But we will agree on one thing - this discussion is fruitless so should end.

Comment: @roganjosh At least we could agree on one point finally :) (Technically the development server acts as a server serving pages, you say it's not one, that was precisely the goal of my question to understand *why* it is not a real one, what would fail by using it, etc. But you preferred to close the question, that's it. What a waste of time. You seem to have the knowledge about why the dev server would fail, and instead of sharing this knowledge, you chose to close the question).

Comment: So you're saying that you got an answer to your question, you just don't like the answer.  That doesn't make your question not a duplicate, sadly, it just means the answer isn't what you wanted it to be.

Comment: @Servy Yes, thanks to these duplicates, people get a vague general answer, you're right. It basically says "Don't use X, it's not good, use X + Y + Z instead". My question's goal was to understand, by an example, why Y and Z are really needed, and why X alone would fail. This precise point - which I think was interesting for developers to understand - has been decided as uninteresting by most people. Never mind. Question closed! Let's use X + Y + Z blindly even if the  educational mission to explain why Y and Z are needed failed. (I don't deny this, I just wanted to understand) I stop here.

Comment: @Basj no, let's not use them blindly. Test it; you have all the tools you need. I have a question; are you able to accept that there's things you don't know, and investigate them? You've pushed back a lot on this issue, and it gets downvoted in multiple places. You can hold your position that SO is set up incorrectly for this kind of question, or use it as a prompt to learn what's missing in your understanding.

Comment: @roganjosh Why continue this discussion again and again when we agreed hours ago it's pointless now? :) Once again, all these answers explain that X + Y + Z are needed, but don't explain why X alone fails, thus my initial question. It's not a big deal, let's stop now, let's have both a good day outside of this question :)

Comment: @Basj But you *have* had it explained to you why you can't use the tool you want to use.  It wasn't built to do what you want to do.  It was built to do something radically different.  *That is the explanation for why you need to use something else*.  That you don't like that answer doesn't change the fact that it's the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Servy. It's not about not liking the answer, it's about *understanding the internal reasons* that make the dev bundled server unadapted for production. The problem is now solved, I have found some helpful answers in some tutorials + discussions, so we can close the discussion. Thanks for having taken the time to give feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a gold badge holder for [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask), I came across your question after it had already been closed as a duplicate. As an expert in the tag, I agreed with the duplicate, and added some extra duplicates that I felt addressed the issue as well. Given the continued misunderstandings of these duplicates you've stated in comments, I'll explain why I felt your question should be closed.

---

Neither duplicate says "blindly use WSGI", and neither one omits an explanation for what they say. They both say "the dev server handles one request at a time by default", which directly answers your question, which was "what happens if multiple requests come in?" The details you've given in your question do not affect the answer, which remains "the dev server handles one request at a time by default" and "use `threaded=True` to let the dev server handle multiple requests."

The answers *also* say "don't use the dev server in production" along with an explanation of why. You seem to be focusing on this part to the exclusion of the first point which directly answers your question, and ignoring that they *also* say why you should use a production WSGI server.

The answer to your question remains "use `threaded=True` for the dev server" and "don't use the dev server to handle production loads." Both duplicates answer both these points. Therefore, I do not feel that your question needs a separate answer, and will leave it closed with the given duplicates.

---

I can't read the minds of the voters, but it seems likely that they also felt the duplicates answered your question. A duplicate is not inherently bad, it acts as a signpost to a common answer. However, you continually insisted that your question was different but failed to sway those other users. They indicated that the other parts of your question were not relevant to the answer. Rather than continue to argue with you, they most likely decided to vote instead to indicate their decision rather than being lenient.

I value all positive contributions in the tag, since it gets a relatively low volume of traffic. Duplicates are not inherently bad, but continued arguing in the face of feedback explaining otherwise is a drain to the limited attention and patience the tag gets. I encourage you to learn from this and to continue to contribute to the tag as you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll accept it. For future reference, my main concern with current questions/answers was that: 1) Argument #1: "the dev server doesn't handle multiple requests" => not really true, as pointed in comments by other people by the way, since we can use `threaded=True`. 2) Argument #2: "If you leave debug mode on and an error pops up, it opens up a shell that allows for arbitrary code to be executed on your server" => this is not a "real" argument. This feature could easily be turned off with a few lines of code.

Comment: 3) A real argument would be "Benchmarks show that the Flask internal server is slower by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude than nginx, as showed in Source A" or "Source B points out that there's the security problem C in the Flask internal server". Lastly, as for the downvotes, I don't care, this is a typical meta effect.

Comment: Finally, probably SO was not the right place for such opinion-based questions, my bad (100% my fault). For future reference, if anyone is interested for more informations, here is a [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8bb102/why_shouldnt_one_use_flask_bottle_django_etc/) I posted on reddit, and the answers were helpful to understand the limitations of the internal Flask server. (sidenote: +15 votes, 77% upvoted, quite a difference ;) so the question in itself is not inherently bad,it shows that people are curious about why technically Flask internal server shouldn't be used).